# How to setup Drupal on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to use Drupal as a CMS and am trying to install Drupal on a AWS AMI EC2 Instance, but I am getting stuck in trying to get Apache Virtual Hosts to work with Drupal. I am unable to use Beanstalk.

I went through Amazon's tutorial (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) to install the LAMP stack onto my EC2 instance.

I started following the steps for Drupal 8 Installation (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install), but the documentation seems incomplete, without much resources as to how to setup Apache Virtual Hosts to work with Drupal.

Any suggestions as how to proceed?

Comment: do you need it for production use? or experimentation?

Comment: @bjliu You can refer this site `https://www.tecmint.com/install-drupal-in-centos-rhel-fedora/` They have explained all the steps properly over here.

Comment: experimentation

Comment: @bjliu if my answer helped, could you please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just ***experimenting with Drupal***, your best bet is to use the quick installation by Bitnami from the AWS Marketplace found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZSUMO).